# Is there a shortcut key to duplicate line in google colab?? If not how can it be implemented?

Tags: google-colaboratory, keyboard-shortcuts

I usually duplicate the line if i need to use the code same as the above line. I did not find the shortcut key to duplicate the line . I saw some posts to implement shortcut key to duplicate line but they are rather complicated and requires to run script every time.

Comment: Do you want to duplicate a single line or the entire cell?

Comment: I want to duplicate the single line

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution just in case anyone wants to use it.

**Alt + Shift + Down_arrow**

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still looking for a keyboard shortcut to duplicate lines in `Google Colab`,
<kbd>Left_Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down_arrow</kbd> works for me!

Comment: not working on ubuntu, maybe something is capturing it.

Answer (score 3):

if you want duplicate a code line or selected code lines just use `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v`. or `ctrl+c+v`

edit:
I've checked after time, now there is a shortcut is

> shift + alt + arrow down or up

Comment: I actually needed a one press shortcut key.

Comment: Unfortunatly there is no just one press shortcut. Most of colab shortcuts are three keys combinations. Also you can use **ctrl** + **c** + **v**

Answer (score 1):

Use this:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow down</kbd>